# jQuery event triggers twice

Tags: jquery, events

Can someone explain to me why this event triggers twice? It doesn't seem to do it on jQuery versions prior to 1.7.

```
<input type="textbox" id="box" onblur="console.log('This will trigger twice!');"/>
<script>
$('#box').blur();
</script>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/EWbmD/52/

Comment: Triggers once for me. Which browser do you use?

Comment: I've tried Chrome, IE11 and Firefox. All seems to have the problem. (Note that the consoles tend to "group" repeated messages, so you might just get one line in the console, but with a "(2)" somewhere)

Comment: Yep I'm aware, but still only once :)

Comment: Ok now I see your problem, showed once before for some reason.

Comment: check this with firbug http://jsfiddle.net/EWbmD/56/

Comment: It seems like jQuery is also firing `focusout` event; both of them trigger the `onblur` function.

Comment: SleepMachine, I updated the answer with a possible solution. (@Salman A, yeah, took me a while to believe, even after Arun P Johny pointed it out, look here http://jsfiddle.net/SvqwF/5/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the internals, it looks like triggering `blur` event is triggering `blur` and `focusout` events internally which is invoking the `onblur` twice.

PoC

```
$('#box').on('blur focusout', function (e) {
    console.log('this too', e.type);
});
$('#box').blur();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SvqwF/)

The [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/blur) event is a non bubbling event, the bubbling counterpart is the [foucsout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/focusout) event. So in normal circumstances the blur operation triggers both these events. So jQuery is trying to be intelligent and fires both these events in case of a blur event, but it looks like there is an bug in the implementation.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is a jQuery bug, or if it is the intended behaviour? If intended, how would you modify/fix my code AND still keep the inline "onBlur"? I do not wish to bind using jQuery.on().

Comment: @SleepMachine I don't think it is the indented behavior because it was suppose to call `onblur` and `onfocusout` handlers instead of calling `onblur` twice - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SvqwF/4/

Comment: Btw, not even to W3C specifications. Blur: A user agent must dispatch this event when an event target loses focus. **The focus must be taken from the element before the dispatch of this event** type. This event type is similar to focusout, but is **dispatched after focus is shifted**, and does not bubble. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-focusevent

Comment: I know this is an old topic but it doesn't seem to be fixed in jQuery. Anybody knows if this is on anybody's list?
I noticed that .trigger("onblur") works, as in the onblur event-handler gets fired only once. Is using "onblur" instead of "blur" good?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This might be a solution to your problem.

## JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/SvqwF/7/

Based on [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/).

---

You trigger it twice, because the [`.blur()`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) is trigger to

```
.on('blur focusout', function(){}) (Thanks to @Arun P Johny)
```

which just triggers the `event listener` you added inline also, if you do not pass a function to `.blur()`. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EWbmD/59/)

Since you added a function inline, that function gets triggered twice.

> Description: Bind an event handler to the "blur" JavaScript event, or **trigger** that event on an element. [jQuery .blur()](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)

To get more about the method (for old IE `.attachEvent`) that is involved with [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js):

> To register more than one event listener for the target, call addEventListener() for the same target but with different event types or capture parameters. [MDN](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.html)

**Note:** I am unsure as to which event to declare in `.on()`, it seems like all work

> The focus and blur events are specified by the W3C to not bubble, but jQuery defines cross-browser "focusin" and "focusout" events that do bubble. When "focus" and "blur" are used to attach delegated event handlers, jQuery maps the names and delivers them as "focusin" and "focusout" respectively. [jQuery .on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

**Note 2:** `blur() <- empty` is a shortcut for `trigger('blur')`. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EWbmD/60/)

Answer (score -1):

You just need to call it once:

```
$('#box').on('blur', function() {
    console.log('This will trigger twice!');
});

$('#box').blur();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EWbmD/57/)**

or just remove your jQuery code and keep your `onblur` event inside your `input` tag.

Comment: but the question why is to getting called twice

Comment: because he call it two times? one is `onblur` and one is triggered through jQuery?

Comment: no.. if you open the fiddle in Chrome and just see the console the message is logged twice