# Primefaces programmatically triggered event fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a pretty simple JSF page with the following primefaces elements:

```
<p:inputText value="#{myBean.myValue}" widgetVar="tbeditorArea">
        <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{myBean.myListener}"/>
</p:inputText>
```

I'd like to trigger the blur event handler which is attached by the p:ajax programmatically.
Doing so, I experience the following strange behaviour:
If I trigger the event by calling it on the nativ DOM Element like this:

```
PF('tbeditorArea').jq.get()[0].onblur()
```

everything's fine. The blur event is triggered only once an only one ajax reqest is send back to the server.

If I trigger the event by calling:

```
PF('tbeditorArea').jq.blur();
```

the blur event fires twice and hence two ajax requests are posted back to the server.

Does anyone know, what causes this strange behaviour?

Comment: Have you got more than one `tbeditorArea` in your HTML?

Comment: Nope, just  one, I already doublechecked this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the JS call stacks to `PrimeFaces.ajax.Queue.offer`, you'll see that the first time `onblur` is triggered with the `blur` event, and the second - with the `focusout` event. This is a jQuery quirk. A bit more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21672117/1341535).

Your workaround is probably good enough. Keep in mind though, that you're not really triggering the event, but directly calling the event handler. This only works because PrimeFaces renders an inline `onblur` handler, instead of adding the event handler with jQuery.